# VBA - Pushing data from one workbook to another, irrespective of file names

Tags: vba, excel

Been in a pickle for a while (week or so) here and was hoping someone in this magical community could help me out. There is likely a very easy solution for an experienced individual, which I am not.

First, my goal is as follows: Push data from Workbook A to Workbook B via macro. 
Conditions:

Workbook A must be able to be renamed without compromising the macro (it is a tool used in day-to-day functions and saved as a new name each use). Workbook A holds the macros.

Workbook B receives the data. Its name will also change with time, but in this case it needs to be based off written text in a cell from Workbook A (name change about yearly due to versioning) Let's just call it Cell A1 for argument's sake.

There may be additional workbooks open at the same time, related or unrelated.

To keep it simple, I will just post one line in my current macro, but I will be applying this to dozens. This works when I do not rename the files. I likely need help defining variables (strings?) and direction in what functions to use.

```
Windows("Workbook_B 4.7.5.xls").Activate
'*Workbook B name will ideally be derived from a cell value in Workbook A*

Range("V12") = "='[Workbook_A V1.2.5 .xlsm]SHEET_A '!R8C7"
```

In this chunk, the goal is to activate Workbook B and copy the value (or formula if it is easier), from cell G8 on Workbook A Sheet A to Workbook B(sheet is already active and sheet names will never change in either workbook).

Cheers!

Comment: The code you provided will never get you to where you want to go and doesn't show any real effort to solve the problem.  All of us here will help you solve problems but we're not here to write your solution.  I suggest you get a book like "Programming Excel with VBA: A Practical Real-World Guide " to help you as you learn about VBA programming.  It will help you solve the problem. When you get stuck with a coding issue ask a question. Your should review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

"Workbook A holds the macros" - in this case you would use

```
ThisWorkbook
```

to refer to Workbook A

...and

```
Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value)
```

to refer to Workbook B